# Secure Delete number of passes

Tags: java, security, overwrite, erase

I am trying to delete a file securely in Java using MappedByteBuffer.
Till now, it is working correctly and the files cannot be recovered by software such as FileScavenger.

At present I am using 3 passes to overwrite a file. However, I came across something called Gutmann method which uses 35 passes. In this context, some people are of the opinion that 3 passes are enough.

Do I really need 35 passes or 3 passes are enough?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/215852/is-using-multiple-passes-for-wiping-a-disk-really-necessary

Answer (score 2):

Since the introduction of journals and copy-on-write file systems, **securely deleting single files without special support of the fs driver became impossible**. Journals keep copies of blocks before writing them to the fs to assure consistency in case of crashes and copy-on-write fs create new data sets and change the internal pointer from the old data to the new data, without touching the old data.

As examples, see this [discussion about the implementation of secure deletion on ext4](http://lwn.net/Articles/462437/) and this [question on how to securely delete files on btrfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62345/securely-delete-files-on-btrfs-filesystem).

And even worse, your hard drive might independently keep copies of the "deleted" blocks around without any hints to the OS. SSDs are especially bad at this, but HDDs also have a smaller region of backup blocks they can use to (virtually) swap out bad blocks in case of failures.

Unfortunately, there aren't really good alternatives to deletion either. You can encrypt the file, but then you have to store the key somewhere erasable, and that is the same problem all over again. LUKS (a full disc encryption software) uses so called anti-forensic-stripes to stretch the key information over a long data set in the hope that at least one of the blocks involved cannot be recovered from swapped out or not yet deleted blocks. But emulating this behavior one layer over the filesystem is also not really a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Secure Deletion is tricky.

If you are overwriting your data correctly on a Hard Disk Drive, then according to NIST overwriting it once is enough. (http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-88/NISTSP800-88_with-errata.pdf)

But if you have a Solid State Drive (SSD), then it's not possible at the moment to securely delete data after writing. The problem here is the internal architecture of it. Since the flash translation layer is responsible for the writing and distribution of your data to the flash cells, you have no possibility to find out where your data has been written. so there is no way to delete it (overwrite the corresponding cells). Also there is, depending on the SSD, up to 20% more capacity reserved, on which you have no access at all, but where some of your data might be. So erasing single files is not possible. For deleting all files there are built in mechanisms by the developers (Secure Erase).

So to answer your question... if you have are using a HDD and your deleting correctly, then yes! 3 times is more than enough. if you have a SSD, not possible!

Best way for now and possibly also in the future is secure deletion via encryption. before you write a file to you storage, you encrypt it and can only decrypt it with a key. if you want to securely delete a file now you just have to get lost of the key so noone can decrypt it again. (Of course that's not trivial either...)